# Is it necessary to call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE) before using textures in OpenGL 2.1?

Tags: opengl, textures

In OpenGL 2.1+ do we need to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE)` before using textures? And if we got trouble with texture, what is may be cause?

**Update:**

I'm using OpenGL 2.1 for Desktop and my step is:

1. Load bmp 24 bit image (I checked in gDebuger and it show my texture ok, so i'm sure my load image procedure not failed).
2. Call several OpenGL functions in `init()` procedude:

   ```
   glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
   ```
3. And in draw_scene():

   ```
   glUseProgram(program);
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
   glUniform1i(uniform_texture, 0);
   ...
   ```
4. Vertex shader (version 120):

   ```
   attribute vec3 vPos;
   attribute vec2 vTexCoord;

   uniform mat4 MV;
   uniform mat4 Projection;

   varying vec2 fragTexCoord;

   void main()
   {
       fragTexCoord = vTexCoord;
       gl_Position = Projection * MV * vPos;
   }
   ```
5. Fragment shader:

   ```
   uniform sampler2D my_texture;
   varying vec2 fragTexCoord;

   void main()
   {
       gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_texture, fragTexCoord);
   }
   ```

Comment: If you're using shaders, then I doubt `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE)` does anything.  Can you give us a screenshot of what you're getting, or describe the problem of the output you have in more detail?

Comment: I think some of my parameters error, I have cleared and rewritten all texture code and now it work! Can any one explain me what differents bettwen `GL_RGBA8`, `GL_RGBA`, ... in `internalFormat`? If i used `GL_RGB` in `internalFormat` then can I access alpha element in fragment shader like: `texture2D(myTexture, texCoord).a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use GLSL shaders in OpenGL 2.1 then the call to `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_*)` has no meaning. You apply texture in your fragment shader.

If you intend to move on to the OpenGL 3.x core profile, keep in mind that `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_*)` is deprecated.